# npm -v. The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed node js on windows 7 from https://nodejs.org/en/download/. When I run **node -v out put is v8.9.4** But when I check **npm -v out put is**

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
5.6.0
```

In path variable entry is as

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

blank npm folder is present on above path

I added entry in path variable as it is recommended in some answer

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
```

but still getting same error. I tried solutions I found online like above path entry, re installation, global installation of npm but still same error

Comment: try to reinstall.

Comment: I tried reinstall 2 to 3 times but same issue

Comment: Try a version manager: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in this article: https://www.thetopsites.net/article/53531888.shtml
"I needed to move my node paths further up the list. Windows must have been looking for NPM in the wrong path variable. I moved my node path to the top of the system path variables and now NPM works."
It helped me after a day of struggle.

Answer (score 1):

More details for the solution provided by @Thomas.K:
Open Windows Settings and search for 'environ' like here:

[image]

Make sure to choose the one for "system environment", and in the dialog which appears press this button:

[image]

You will get this dialog

[image]

There are two PATH declarations, at top and bottom. You will have to remove the *npm* entry off the upper list, and paste it into the top of the lower list. This should solve the problem of "The system cannot find the path specified".